# Vue component error: Expected Function, got String

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, button, components

I'm using ionic with vue to develop an app. I made a custom button and want to include in another component. I'm trying to assign a function to the button but doesnt seem to work. The error i got is this:

**[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "onClick". Expected Function, got String with value "addTodo".**

First time using vue.Thanks in advance.

**Button component**

```
<template>
<ion-footer>
    <ion-button fill="outline" expand="block" color="primary" @click="onClick">
        <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
        {{text}}
    </ion-button>
</ion-footer>
</template>
<script>
export default {
props: {
    onClick:Function,
    text:String,
}
}
</script>
```

**Another Component**

```
<template>
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <main-btn text="Add Activity" onClick="addTodo"></main-btn>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid> 
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
       return {
         todos: []
          }
    },
    methods: {
      addTodo() {
    this.$router.push({path: '/todos/add'})
   }
  },
    created() {
       axios.get('http://localhost:3001/todos')
     .then(res => this.todos = res.data)
   }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: did you try `onClick="addTodo()"` or `:onClick="addTodo()"`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim doesnt work

Comment: `:onClick="addTodo"`?

Answer (score 2):

Just change it up, you don't need to pass the function as a prop.

In your button component:

```
@click="$emit('click')"
```

In your "Another Component"

```
<main-btn text="Add Activity" @click="addTodo"></main-btn>
```

Just bubble up the click event from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Your going backwards against the way Vue is intended to work. You always want to pass Props Down which consist of data the child components need and emit events upwards to the parents to handle the necessary function calls.

Your child component "main-btn" should look more like below

```
<ion-button fill="outline" expand="block" color="primary" @click="$emit("onClick")">
    <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
    {{text}}
</ion-button>
```

This will allow any parent components to look for the onClick Event emitted by the child component and react accordingly. In your case the parent component only needs to change slightly.

```
  <ion-col>
    <main-btn text="Add Activity" @onClick="addTodo"></main-btn>
  </ion-col>
```

The parent component is looking for an onClick event and reacts accordingly by calling its addTodo function

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events